# Como faço para voltar check in que eu fiz no TFVC?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Preciso voltar atrás em alguns check ins, não queria ter que buscar o último código válido e fazer check in por cima, e sim apagar essas entradas no controle de versão. É possível fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o seu código está no TFVC, antes existia uma funcionalidade de Rollback no Team Foundation Power Tools, ela foi movida para o TF.exe!

Para usar:

```
tf rollback /changeset:changesetfrom~changesetto [itemspec] [/recursive]
[/lock:none|checkin|checkout] [/version:versionspec]
[/keepmergehistory] [/noprompt] [/login:username,[password]]

tf rollback /toversion:versionspec itemspec [/recursive] 
[/lock:none|checkin|checkout] [/version:versionspec]
[/keepmergehistory] [/noprompt] [/login:username,[password]]
```

Para voltar para uma versão específica o parâmetro que deve ser utilizado é o **/toversion**

A ajuda para o comando pode ser encontrada aqui: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776.aspx

Também é possível executar no VS.Net de maneira visual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956.aspx#to_one

Comment: Não tenho reputação suficiente pra dar upvote (ainda), mas isso resolve meu problema. Muito obrigado!!